# With statements inside an Insert statement HIVE EMR AWS

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive, hdfs, amazon-emr

Hive does not recognize my WITH statement inside of an INSERT command.
How can I make hive understand this?

I've created the external hive tables to store all of the data referenced in this query. That all executes fine and the data is available. This is the actual meat of the query that will be inserting the output into the churn_date_out table.

To put this output set into the table I'm using an insert command that then goes through the with functions to build the output data. However, as soon as it starts, Hive does not like the WITH statement.

The WITH statements cascade through each other and the final output is selected from the revenue piece. None of that is really relevant as long as we can figure out how to get Hive to like the WITH statement.

I really appreciate any ideas! Thank you.

```
 FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'WITH' 'customers' 'AS' in statement


INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE churn_data_out partition (month) (
WITH customers AS (
  SELECT c.cust_nm,
         aef.cust_key,
         min(date (SUBSTR(cast(cal.brdcsts_yr_mo_nbr AS VARCHAR),1,4) || '-' || SUBSTR(cast(cal.brdcst_yr_mo_nbr AS VARCHAR),5,6) || '-01')) AS first_payment,
         max(date (SUBSTR(cast(cal.brdcst_yr_mo_nbr AS VARCHAR),1,4) || '-' || SUBSTR(cast(cal.brdcst_yr_mo_nbr AS VARCHAR),5,6) || '-01')) AS last_payment
  FROM am_ad_event_fact_in as aef
INNER JOIN am_calendar_dim cal
    ON date_parse(aef.ad_evnt_start_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') = cal.clndr_dt
        AND cal.BRDCST_YR_NBR >= 2015
INNER JOIN am_eda_customer_dim c
    ON (aef.cust_key = c.cust_key)
  GROUP BY 1,2),

  months AS (
    SELECT month
FROM (SELECT sequence(date '2010-01-01', current_date, interval '1' month)
) AS x (i)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(i) AS t (month)
),

athenasux AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (customers as c
    INNER JOIN months as month
              ON (c.first_payment <= month))),


revenue AS (
    SELECT a.*,
    row_number() over (partition by a.cust_nm order by month) AS months_as_customer,
    max(case when aef.prio_cd >= 40 then 1 else 0 end) p40plus,
    sum(case when aef.spot_rate_nbr is null then 0 else aef.spot_rate_nbr end) as rev,
    count(aef.ad_evnt_key) as spots,
    count(distinct aef.ord_nbr) as num_orders,
    count(distinct syscode) num_syscodes
    FROM athenasux as a
    LEFT JOIN am_ad_event_fact_in as aef
    ON (aef.cust_key = a.cust_key
    AND date_parse(aef.ad_evnt_start_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') = a.month)
    GROUP BY a.cust_nm, a.cust_key, a.month, a.first_payment, a.last_payment
  )


SELECT *,
    sum(rev) over (partition by cust_key, cust_nm order by month
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) rev_rt,
    sum(num_orders) over (partition by cust_key, cust_nm order by month
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) num_orders_rt,
    sum(spots) over (partition by cust_key, cust_nm order by month
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) spots_rt,
    sum(num_syscodes) over (partition by cust_key, cust_nm order by month
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) num_syscodes_rt
FROM revenue
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax wise, `insert` should be used at the end of all cte's and the beginning of the last `SELECT`.

```
with cte1 as (...)
,cte2 as (...)
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT ....
```

Comment: Thank you, by moving the insert statement to the last select statement it is getting new errors which is exciting. I'll keep you posted.